# How to get number of User in Firebase as a count In android TextView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

As per the picture the database has one user so it should give a number 1 in a textview at corner of loginactivity as per New user entry it should increase

Comment: Sounds like a pretty decent requirement. Which part are you having trouble with? To get started reading from the Firebase database, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, If you want the count to be increase everytime, when new user entry in database then better to use `ChildEventListener`.

```
    int studentCounter = 0;// declare int variable



    TextView tv_counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_counter);

    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("student");


    mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            studentCounter = studentCounter + 1;

            //Convert counter to string
            String strCounter = String.valueOf(studentCounter);

            //Showing the user counter in the textview
            tv_counter.setText(strCounter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This starts the counter always at 0, and never counts existing users, only new ones

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Using this my answer is 1 student. But I am only reading one time. If I add other student the counter will don't change until the activity is updated.

```
  TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);

  Database database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

  DatabaseReference  studentsRef = database.getReference("student");

  studentsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            int counter = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

            //Convert counter to string
            String userCounter = String.valueOf(counter);

            //Showing the user counter in the textview
            yourTextView.setText(userCounter);



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

But If you want to have the real time counter you should change addListenerForSingleValueEvent to addValueEventListener like this...

```
studentsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            int counter = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

            //Convert counter to string
            String userCounter = String.valueOf(counter);

            //Showing the user counter in the textview
            yourTextView.setText(userCounter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

With the last code when I enter a new student my counter will change immediately, and if I delete a student my counter will change immediately too.